Help to clarify the informations on this paragraph about M-theory

"A similar construction - On how to obtain the $D6$-brane of Type
IIA string theory from the M-theory, using analogy with the
Kaluza-Klein monopole and Taub-NUT metric - applies to other string
theories compactified on circles. Indeed, the type IIB superstring
theory compactified on a circle contains a Kaluza–Klein $5$-brane,
constructed in the same way as the D$6$- brane, which is the magnetic
dual of the Kaluza–Klein $0$-brane. A T-duality transformation along
the circular dimension transforms the type IIB theory into the type
IIA theory compactified on the dual circle. The Kaluza–Klein $0$-brane
is dual to a fundamental type IIA string wound on the dual circle.
Therefore, the Kaluza–Klein $5$-brane must map to the magnetic dual of
the fundamental IIA string, which is the type IIA NS5-brane."

This quote is from Becker/Becker/Schwarz book on String Theory. The bold part is from myself.
I am having some problem to understand the information contained above, see:
It seems, to me, that we want to understand how to obtain the D-5 brane (IIB) from M-theory. The first question already arises:
Why he calls D-5 brane the KK 5-brane? (I understand how the D-0 brane from IIA arises as KK-excitations in D=11 dimensions, is this the same logic here?)
The main problem is about the last three,two lines!

"The Kaluza–Klein 0-brane is dual to a fundamental type IIA string
wound on the dual circle."

What does he mean? The 0-brane, as far as i remember, is dual to the D-p brane, that is, 6 brane here. But fundamental type IIA string is 1-brane! Well, I thought, maybe we are talking about T-duality. But $0$-brane is a type IIA object, so it does not make sense a T duality between Type IIA to type IIA (from 0brane type IIA to 1brane type IIA)

" Therefore, the Kaluza–Klein 5
-brane must map to the magnetic dual of the fundamental IIA string, which is the type IIA NS5-brane."

This I can't simply understand the logic, and I think the main reason is because I didn't got the phrase before this one...
